# Filter Array with callback function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of object **arrayOfUsers** as below and i want to filter that **dynamically** based on the object **filterValues**. If i remove **name** from **filterValues** the code should filter the array with **age** only and if i add **id** also to **filterValues** it should filter the array with three properties with out directly specifying key in the filter code and the key should capture from **filterValues**. I would like to get a solution for this using **callback** function. Appreciate for the solutions.

```
const arrayOfUsers = [
 { id: 1, name: 'Sam', age: 33 },
 { id: 2, name: 'Ram', age: 34 },
 { id: 3, name: 'Raj', age: 32 },
 { id: 4, name: 'Som', age: 2 }]

const filterValues = { name: 'R', age: 3 }
```

Expected Output:

```
[
 { id: 2, name: 'Ram', age: 34 },
 { id: 3, name: 'Raj', age: 32 }
]
```

Here is the sample code where i am stuck on.

```
const test = (arr) => {
  Object.keys(filterValues).map((key, i) => arr.filter((user) => user[key].includes(key[i])))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the properties to string and seach for a substring.

```js
const
    arrayOfUsers = [{ id: 1, name: 'Sam', age: 33 }, { id: 2, name: 'Ram', age: 34 }, { id: 3, name: 'Raj', age: 32 }, { id: 4, name: 'Som', age: 2 }],
    filterValues = { name: 'R', age: 3 },
    filters = Object.entries(filterValues),
    result = arrayOfUsers.filter(user => filters.every(([key, value]) =>
        user[key].toString().includes(value)
    ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```